# Why doesn't object dot notation work for objects of unknown type? (TypeError: undefined is not an object)

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, typeerror

I'm writing a physics simulator with particles and one of the functions I need is the `distanceTo` function which allows a particle to find out its distance to another particle of input called `other`. When I run this script, the error log shows:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object on line 11.

The error appears to be in `other.pos[i]` but I don't know how else to find the `pos` variable of the `other` object.

```
1     function Particle(mass, radius, pos, vel) {
2          this.mass = mass;
3          this.radius = radius;
4          this.pos = pos;
5          this.vel = vel;
6     
7          this.distanceTo = function(other) {
8              var k = 0;
9              var l = this.pos.length;
10             for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
11                 k += Math.pow(this.pos[i] - other.pos[i], 2);
12             }
13             return Math.sqrt(k);
14         }
15           
16         this.scan = function(range, limit) {
17             for (var r in range) {
18                 if (this.distanceTo(r) <= limit){
19                     return "within the limit";
20                 } else {
21                     return "outside the limit";
22                 }
23             }
24         }
25     }
26
27     var p1 = new Particle(1, 0.1, [0, 0], [0, 0]);
28     var p2 = new Particle(1, 0.1, [10, -2], [0, 0]);
29
30     console.log(p1.distanceTo(p2));
31     console.log(p1.scan([p2], 10));
```

Comment: The `for` loop in your "scan" function doesn't make a lot of sense, since it will always return from the function on the very first iteration regardless of what "range" looks like.

Comment: Yeah I'm just testing that. I realize that it exits strangely.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a JSFiddle / StackOverflow code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

In

```
for (var r in range) {
```

`r` will be `0` - the first and only index of `range` array. Then `this.distanceTo(r)` will fail.

Comment: Should it be `this.distanceTo(range[r])`

Comment: @BrandonGomes - yes, but you should simply use `for(var iter = 0; iter < range.length; iter++)` and revise your return logic.

Comment: But you are going about it an awkward way. It is an array. You should really use a standard for loop. You are passing [p2]

Comment: Thanks @Shaun, i was thinking i could use less code thats all

Comment: It's dangerous with arrays. You will usually get the same result, but you're iterating around the prototype properties not the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you doing the `for...in` in the first place, but if I remove the loop and pass the obj as argument for both function seems to work ok.

Check if this works for you:

```
function Particle(mass, radius, pos, vel) {
  this.mass = mass;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.pos = pos;
  this.vel = vel;

  this.distanceTo = function(other) {
    var k = 0;
    var l = this.pos.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
      k += Math.pow(this.pos[i] - other.pos[i], 2);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(k);
  };

  this.scan = function(range, limit) {
    if (this.distanceTo(range) <= limit){
        return "within the limit";
      } else {
        return "outside the limit";
      }
  };
}

var p1 = new Particle(1, 0.1, [0, 0], [0, 0]);
var p2 = new Particle(1, 0.1, [10, -2], [0, 0]);

console.log(p1.distanceTo(p2)); // 10.198039027185569
console.log(p1.scan(p2, 10)); // "outside the limit"
```